# Como eu posso quebrar linhas de uma ErrorMessage de uma Data Annotation?

Tags: c#, dataannotations

Eu tenho essa propriedade e as Data Annotations para ela:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo orbgiatório.")]
[RegularExpression("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,}$", ErrorMessage = "The password must contain: \n * Pelo menos 8 caracteres; \n *Pelo menos uma letra. \n *Pelo menos um dígito. ")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Eu quero pular as linhas da mensagem de erro entre cada regra de senha, por isso estou usando o **\n**, mas não está funcionando. O **\n** apenas desaparece e a mensagem não quebra as linhas.

Comment: Try it the Windows way`\r\n`. `\n` is Unix style.

Comment: Btw. Why do you post an English question on a Portuguese site?

Comment: Olá. Pf coloque a sua questão em Português, está no **SOpt**. Já tentou colocar `Environment.NewLine` ao invés de `\n`?

Comment: Confundi as contas, perdão :D

Comment: Nem \r\n nem Enviroment.NewLine funcionaram, infelizmente.

Comment: Onde você está exibindo essa mensagem? Console App, Windows App ou Web App?

Comment: É uma página web. Mas usar <br> do html na mensagem, como você respondeu, não funcionou. A mensagem só exibe o <br>. O que é bem estranho, porque no seu exemplo, funcionou;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você está exibindo essa validação apenas em uma aplicação web você pode utilizar as tags do html para isso:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo orbgiatório.")]
[RegularExpression(
        "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,}$", 
        ErrorMessage = "<b>The password must contain:</b> <br> *Pelo menos 8 caracteres; <br> *Pelo menos uma letra. <br> *Pelo menos um dígito."
    )]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]